# Confirmation dialog/SweetAlert dialog before Ajax POST

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms, sweetalert

I have an Ajax POST function which submits a form. In my beforeSend() function I have a sweetAlert dialog which will either abort or continue the Ajax POST call. My problem is that the success function triggers before the beforeSend() is complete, ie, it won't wait for the user to select one of the options in the sweetAlert dialog. How can I pause the Ajax call until the sweetAlert dialog is complete?

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    beforeSend: function(data) {
        swal({
            buttons: ["No", "Yes"],
            successMode: true,
        }).then((yes) => {
            if (yes) {
                swal("Success", {
                    icon: "success",
                    buttons: false,
                });
            } else {
                data.abort()
            }
        });

    },
    success: function(data) {
       // success functions
    },
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve but if I'm understanding correctly you can insert the ajax POST into the swal itself.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. I want the sweetAlert confirmation dialog to determine if the Ajax function should post the form data or not.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I pause the Ajax call until the sweetAlert dialog is complete?

You can't. It is asynchronous.

The closest you could come would be to *always* abort the request, and then resend it (without the abort) after the user clicked "Yes".